# Better routing in Yii

Tags: yii, url-routing

I'm new to Yii. I have a controller like this:

```
<?php

class EventsController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

How can i make the following url render the correct view. eg.

```
localhost/events/intaglio -> $this->render('intaglio');
localhost/events/burrito-> $this->render('burrito');
localhost/events/jerrito -> $this->render('jerrito');
```

Worse case, I'll have to have separate actions for each

```
public function actionIntagio {...}
public function actionBurrito {...}
public function actionJerrito {...}
```

Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: Use `CUrlManager`, define a rule that forwards all those URLs to a common action. It's hard to tell what those views do, though, there might be a better solution still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup URL rules (in *protected/config/main.php*) to handle those URL's dynamically, eg:

```
events/<event_name:.+> => events/myaction
```

This points any URL with *events/whatever*  to the Controller/Action *events/myaction*. You can then access the `event_name` portion of the URL with a `$_GET` variable, eg:

```
echo $_GET['event_name'];
```